# R fPortfolio covariance risk budget constraint

Tags: r, constraints, portfolio

I have a question connect with fPortfolio. In my case I have three assets and I want to optimize portfolio from those assets, but I want each asset to have the same risk part in my portfolio. For that purpose I use budgetconstraints <-c( “min[c(1:3)] = rep(0.32,times = 3)”,”max[c(1:3)] =rep(0.34,times=3)"

> print(mySpec)
>   Model List: 
>    Type:                      MV
>    Optimize:                  minRisk
>    Estimator:                 covEstimator
>    Params:                    alpha = 0.05 a = 1

Portfolio List: 
 Target Weights:            NULL
 Target Return:             NULL
 Target Risk:               NULL
 Risk-Free Rate:            0
 Number of Frontier Points: 50
 Status:                    NA

Optim List: 
 Solver:                    solveRquadprog
 Objective:                 portfolioObjective portfolioReturn portfolioRisk
 Options:                   meq = 2
 Trace:                     FALSE

When I use backtest with minvaraincePortfolio I discover the constraint not work, I compare with backtest with the same function minvariancePortfolio  without constraint but the results are the same. If someone have any idea how to solve the problem please help me. THANKS